# How to save bio using forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I tried multiple links on stackov. but none worked, I can't get my **bio** form to save the data on the db for the user profile :/

I managed to save the first name and last name, but I can't make the bio save... This is my code:

**profile.html**

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}

                                <label for="first_name">
                                    <h4>First name</h4>
                                </label>
                                {{ user_ProfileForm.first_name |as_crispy_field }}

                                <label for="last_name">
                                    <h4>Last name</h4>
                                </label>
                                {{ user_ProfileForm.last_name |as_crispy_field }}
                                <p>
                                {{ user_BioAndSocialForm.bio |as_crispy_field }}
                                </p>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <hr>
                </div>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_ProfileForm = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        user_BioAndSocialForm = BioAndSocialForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if user_ProfileForm.is_valid() and user_BioAndSocialForm.is_valid():
            user_ProfileForm.save()
            user_BioAndSocialForm.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Profile updated!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))

    else:
        user_ProfileForm = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        user_BioAndSocialForm = BioAndSocialForm(instance=request.user)

    context = {
        'user_ProfileForm': user_ProfileForm,
        'user_BioAndSocialForm': user_BioAndSocialForm
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class BioAndSocialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['bio']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BioAndSocialForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    #Image feature upload
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    # If we don't have this, it's going to say profile object only
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'  # it's going to print username Profile

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

            img = Image.open(self.image.path)

            if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.image.path)
```

When I hit update, the first and last name save well but the bio doesn't save.

Thank you head of time

Comment: if user_ProfileForm.is_valid() and user_BioAndSocialForm.is_valid: <=== user_BioAndSocialForm.is_valid()

Comment: ups I totally missed that, thanks. But it still doesn't save it :/

Comment: Check if user_BioAndSocialForm.is_valid() is returning False ?

Comment: How can I check that? I wrote after user_BioAndSocialForm.save() a simple print: print(user_BioAndSocialForm) and it says that it has the form with the content and html format

Comment: It says True :/

Comment: Please check the values in request.POST ?

Comment: Isn't this correct? BioAndSocialForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187403/discussion-between-rambarun-komaljeet-and-arturo).

Comment: I found the error! :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error! Since the bio is in the profile, it is there that I have to take it from:

```
instance=request.user.profile
```

Thanks for the hints Rambarun Komaljeet